# jQuery tabs. I want to make tab content height equal to the largest content tab, to prevent varying heights on different tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm making a tabbed view very similar to this demo:         http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});
});
```

However when you click on different tabs, the container height changes to match its content. How can I have the container height set to the largest possible height of whatever tabbed content there is to avoid the container jumping and changing height? Keep in mind I will be pulling dynamic content into the tabs so I can't set a fixed height in css.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get height of an element with jQuery.

```
$(".class").height();
```

Then, apply this value to other element. Classe names are for example.

```
var h = $(".tabs-menu").height();
$(".tab-content").css("height", h);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the largest height of your tabs and then give the the largest height to all tabs.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/Us8uc/4038/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxHeight = $('.tab div').height();

  $('.tab div').each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight < $('.tab div').height() ? $('.tab div').height() : maxHeight;

  });

  $('.tab div').height(maxHeight);


  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.tabs-menu {
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.tabs-menu li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
}
.tabs-menu li.current {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}
.tabs-menu li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs-menu .current a {
  color: #2e7da3;
}
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto;
}
.tab-content {
  width: 660px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
#tab-1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est
        at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum
        mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies
        arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies
        fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper
        eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra.</p>

    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      <p>Duis egestas fermentum ipsum et commodo. Proin bibendum consectetur elit, hendrerit porta mi dictum eu. Vestibulum adipiscing euismod laoreet. Vivamus lobortis tortor a odio consectetur pulvinar. Proin blandit ornare eros dictum fermentum. Class
        aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur laoreet, ante aliquet molestie laoreet, lectus odio fringilla purus, id porttitor erat velit vitae mi. Nullam posuere nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum.
        Donec suscipit eros nec leo condimentum fermentum. Nunc quis libero massa. Integer tempus laoreet lectus id interdum. Integer facilisis egestas dui at convallis. Praesent elementum nisl et erat iaculis a blandit ligula mollis. Vestibulum vitae
        risus dui, nec sagittis arcu. Nullam tortor enim, placerat quis eleifend in, viverra ac lacus. Ut aliquam sapien ut metus hendrerit auctor dapibus justo porta.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt quam, in egestas dui tincidunt non. Maecenas tempus condimentum mi, sed convallis tortor iaculis eu. Cras dui dui, tempor quis tempor vitae, ullamcorper in justo. Integer et lorem diam. Quisque consequat lectus eget
        urna molestie pharetra. Cras risus lectus, lobortis sit amet imperdiet sit amet, eleifend a erat. Suspendisse vel luctus lectus. Sed ac arcu nisi, sit amet ornare tellus. Pellentesque nec augue a nibh pharetra scelerisque quis sit amet felis.
        Nullam at enim at lacus pretium iaculis sit amet vel nunc. Praesent sapien felis, tincidunt vitae blandit ut, mattis at diam. Suspendisse ac sapien eget eros venenatis tempor quis id odio. Donec lacus leo, tincidunt eget molestie at, pharetra
        cursus odio.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```